# Cannot open file for reading PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to open a file but for some reason I cannot even though the file is there and even has 777 permission. The code is the following:

```
$fileatt = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/a.pdf";
echo "File size is ".filesize($fileatt)."<br>";
if (file_exists($fileatt)) {
    echo "The file ".$fileatt." exist <br>";

    $file = fopen($fileatt, ‘rb’);
    if ($file == false) {
        echo "Could not open the file !";
    }
} else {
    echo "The file ".$fileatt." does NOT exist <br>";
}
```

The result is:

```
File size is 1252121
The file /opt/lampp/htdocs/a.pdf exist 
Could not open the file !
```

Why can't I open the file ? Where is my mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you literally have `‘rb’` in your code or did that mess up while copy-pasting?

Comment: What's the file permissions on the file? if its not an overly importany file try chmod 0777 a.pdf and failing that, check to see if fopen can actually open a pdf :P

Comment: no, I have rb but I have the same behavior even if I only put r

Comment: The point is that the single quotes around `rb` are not normal single quotes.

Comment: Tryed with fopen($fileatt, "rb"); and it seems to work ... thanks skyuzo ...

Comment: Lesson: don't copy-paste random code from the web into your app, especially if the page author uses fancy quotation marks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where is my mistake ?

You don't have error reporting properly set. there are 2 things to remember.

1. error reporting level. set by `error_reporting` ini directive or `error_reporting()` function. should ALWAYS be at E_ALL or higher.
2. error messages destination.

   - on a **development** server it should be display
   - on a live server it should be a log file

Thus, for a quick solution, put these 2 lines at the top of your script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

but later set up these settings as a permanent ones for the whole site (according to the server state)

once you done it, you will have an answer to your question.
Note that you will have not a mere *guess* from the fellow stackoverflowers, but **exact explanation of the matter** from the system itself.

Comment: Which will probably show `Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘rb’ - assumed '‘rb’'`.

Comment: it can be "permission denied" as well.